# Is it possible to redefine a projection in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

Is it possible to redefine a projection in QGis?

It seems like the shape files offered by Agiv (a Flemish agency) differ slightly from the definition that QGis has of EPSG:31370.

I'm NOT looking to create a custom projection, only to replace the existing one.

Update: the definition Agiv (official Flemish agency) uses, becomes this in QGis if you add a shapefile. It is considered a user defined coordinate system, generated CRS, USER:100000.

- Generated CRS (+proj=lcc +lat_1=49.8333339 +lat_2=51.16666723333333 +lat_0=90 +lon_0=4.367486666666666 **+x_0=150000.01256** **+y_0=5400088.4378** +ellps=intl +towgs84=-106.869,52.2978,-103.724,0.3366,-0.457,1.8422,-1.2747 +units=m +no_defs)

The definition of the EPSG:31370 in QGis for EPSG:31370 is:
+proj=lcc +lat_1=51.16666723333333 +lat_2=49.8333339 +lat_0=90 +lon_0=4.367486666666666 **+x_0=150000.013** **+y_0=5400088.438** +ellps=intl +towgs84=-106.869,52.2978,-103.724,0.3366,-0.457,1.8422,-1.2747 +units=m +no_defs

So there's only a very very minor difference, but it seems QGis won't recognize it by default. That's what I'd like to change. (I know I could define it manually). That's how the files are provided, and how they are recognized in ArcGIS, which shows the same False_Easting and False_Northing.

Comment: Probably best to right-click your layer and select **Save As...** then select your CRS from there.

Comment: What is the crs definition ? How does it differ from the official EPSG:31370 ?

Answer (score 3):

There is only one official definition of the EPSG:31370 projection but several "dialects" to represent it (look at [Spatial Reference: EPSG:31370](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/31370/) or [epsg io: 31370](http://epsg.io/31370))

The official [OGC](http://www.opengeospatial.org/) WKT string is:

```
PROJCS["Belge 1972 / Belgian Lambert 72",GEOGCS["Belge 1972",DATUM["Reseau_National_Belge_1972",SPHEROID["International 1924",6378388,297,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7022"]],TOWGS84[-106.869,52.2978,-103.724,0.3366,-0.457,1.8422,-1.2747],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6313"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4313"]],PROJECTION["Lambert_Conformal_Conic_2SP"],PARAMETER["standard_parallel_1",51.16666723333333],PARAMETER["standard_parallel_2",49.8333339],PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",90],PARAMETER["central_meridian",4.367486666666666],PARAMETER["false_easting",150000.013],PARAMETER["false_northing",5400088.438],UNIT["metre",1,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],AXIS["X",EAST],AXIS["Y",NORTH],AUTHORITY["EPSG","31370"]]
```

It is used in the .qpj files of QGIS.

ESRI use its own WKT string:

```
PROJCS["Belge_1972_Belgian_Lambert_72",GEOGCS["GCS_Belge 1972",DATUM["D_Belge_1972",SPHEROID["International_1924",6378388,297]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]],PROJECTION["Lambert_Conformal_Conic"],PARAMETER["standard_parallel_1",51.16666723333333],PARAMETER["standard_parallel_2",49.8333339],PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",90],PARAMETER["central_meridian",4.367486666666666],PARAMETER["false_easting",150000.013],PARAMETER["false_northing",5400088.438],UNIT["Meter",1]]
```

It is used in the .prj files

If you look at the boreholes of [AGIV: G3Dv2_boringen](http://www.geopunt.be/catalogus/datasetfolder/18fbcb78-43ea-47f5-8a61-d3835f21eaff), for example,  they use the ESRI dialect in their .prj files and they are recognised by QGIS:

[image]

Other libraries and applications use different  "dialects" as the [Proj4](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/31370/proj4/) format, as QGIS in the definition of a projection:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If the shapefile comes with a `.prj` file, you can edit that with any text editor.

Once you have saved the file with QGIS, make sure to delete the `.qpj` file, which will be loaded instead of the `.prj` file when present.

Note that the `.prj` file normally does not offer datum shifts. If you don not like the one that QGIS bundles with an EPSG code, you **have** to build a custom CRS.

---

**Update**

Alternatively, you can `Rightclick -> Set CRS for Layer` to ovveride the custom CRS that QGIS has created.

Or install the SQLite Database Browser GUI, open `.../apps/qgis/resources/srs.db`, look up `31370` in field `srid` of table `tbl_srs` and change the values in the `parameters` field. After restarting QGIS this will be permanently on your side, until you install the next QGIS version.